# Jpa Criteria for ManyToMany and OneToOne relationships

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many, criteria-api, one-to-one

I have 3 POJO classes - Link, LinkDetails and Tag.
The relationship between Link and LinkDetails - OneToOne, between LinkDetails and Tag - ManyToMany.

How to use Jpa Criteria, find a list of links with a specified tag name ?

```
@Entity
public class Link extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String url;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private LinkDetails linkDetails;
}

@Entity
public class LinkDetails extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;    

    @Column
    private String description;

    @JoinTable(name = "link_details_2_tag", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "link_details_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id") })
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Tag.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Tag> tags = new TreeSet<Tag>();

}

@Entity
public class Tag extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: Where is your criteria code?There is documentation with examples here https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html

Comment: I have already found a solution. Now it will add it

Comment: I have flagged this question, because it does not ask anything that is not covered by the basic use of criteria api. The case is entirely covered by the documentation. It is not useful to other users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Override
public List<Link> getLinksByTag(String tag){

    CriteriaBuilder cBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Link> criteria = cBuilder.createQuery( Link.class );
    Root<Link> linkRoot = criteria.from( Link.class );
    Join<Link, LinkDetails> linkDetailsJoin = linkRoot.join(Link_.linkDetails);
    Join<LinkDetails, Tag> tagJoin = linkDetailsJoin.join(LinkDetails_.tags);
    criteria.select(linkRoot);
    criteria.where(cBuilder.equal(tagJoin.get(Tag_.name), tag));
    TypedQuery<Link> query = getEntityManager().createQuery(criteria);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```